# Remove similar names into list

Tags: python

I have a list of objects with 3 properties: `full_name`, `subject` and `score`.

As you can see in my list some people names repeat, what I want to do is to remove similar names and instead write scores array and subjects together.

To understand better please the the example below:

```py
a = [{'full_name': 'Douglas Seats', 'subject': 'English', 'score': 51},
 {'full_name': 'Lucille Missey', 'subject': 'Biology', 'score': 19},
 {'full_name': 'Donna Love', 'subject': 'Math', 'score': 3},
 {'full_name': 'Billy Backey', 'subject': 'Math', 'score': 45},
 {'full_name': 'Donna Love', 'subject': 'Math', 'score': 3},
 {'full_name': 'Billy Backey', 'subject': 'Math', 'score': 45},
 {'full_name': 'Douglas Seats', 'subject': 'English', 'score': 51}]
```

What I'm achieving:

```py
{'full_name': 'Douglas Seats, 'subject': {‘English’: [51], ‘Biology’: [53]}},
{'full_name': 'Donna Love', 'subject': {‘Math’: [3], ‘Biology’: [13]}},
{'full_name': 'Billy Backey', 'subject': {‘Math’: [82,49],}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated <3

Comment: is that the desired output that you have added?

Comment: @gold_cy     yes, that's what I want to get

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match your input data.  Where do Billy's 82 and 49 scores come from?  How does Donna have a Biology score?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a straightforward solution.

You use dict with Person's name to group their scored

```
a = [{'full_name': 'Douglas Seats', 'subject': 'English', 'score': 51},
 {'full_name': 'Lucille Missey', 'subject': 'Biology', 'score': 19},
 {'full_name': 'Donna Love', 'subject': 'Math', 'score': 3},
 {'full_name': 'Billy Backey', 'subject': 'Math', 'score': 45},
 {'full_name': 'Donna Love', 'subject': 'Math', 'score': 3},
 {'full_name': 'Billy Backey', 'subject': 'Math', 'score': 45},
 {'full_name': 'Douglas Seats', 'subject': 'English', 'score': 51}]

grouped_items = {}

for item in a:
    full_name = item['full_name']
    if full_name not in grouped_items:
        # Found new person, adding to dict
        grouped_items[full_name] = {
            "full_name": full_name,
            'subject': {}
        }

    subject = item['subject']
    if subject not in grouped_items[full_name]['subject']:
        # Found new subject for person, adding to person's subject dict
        grouped_items[full_name]['subject'][subject] = []

    score = item['score']
    grouped_items[full_name]['subject'][subject].append(score)

items = list(grouped_items.values())

print(items)
```

Output

```
[
{'full_name': 'Douglas Seats', 'subject': {'English': [51, 51]}},
{'full_name': 'Lucille Missey', 'subject': {'Biology': [19]}},
{'full_name': 'Donna Love', 'subject': {'Math': [3, 3]}},
{'full_name': 'Billy Backey', 'subject': {'Math': [45, 45]}}
]
```

Comment: in your output duplicates are being stores.

Comment: For me it seems like you twice got the same score for some subject. So, you should store dupes

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help. I used set because I don't want to remove the duplicates from the list, as that will required more then n*n complexity.

```
a = [
   {'full_name': 'Douglas Seats', 'subject': 'English', 'score': 51},
   {'full_name': 'Lucille Missey', 'subject': 'Biology', 'score': 19},
   {'full_name': 'Donna Love', 'subject': 'Math', 'score': 3},
   {'full_name': 'Billy Backey', 'subject': 'Math', 'score': 45},
   {'full_name': 'Donna Love', 'subject': 'Math', 'score': 3},
   {'full_name': 'Billy Backey', 'subject': 'Math', 'score': 45},
   {'full_name': 'Douglas Seats', 'subject': 'English', 'score': 51}
]

output_dict = {}
for obj in a:
   name = obj['full_name']
   subject = obj['subject']
   score = obj['score']
   if name not in output_dict:
      output_dict[name] = {}
   if subject not in output_dict[name]:
      # use set instead of list to remove the doubles.
      output_dict[name][subject] = set()
   output_dict[name][subject].add(score)

print(output_dict)
```

output

```
{'Douglas Seats': {'English': {51}}, 'Lucille Missey': {'Biology': {19}}, 'Donna Love': {'Math': {3}}, 'Billy Backey': {'Math': {45}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> a = [{'full_name': 'Douglas Seats', 'subject': 'English', 'score': 51},
...  {'full_name': 'Lucille Missey', 'subject': 'Biology', 'score': 19},
...  {'full_name': 'Donna Love', 'subject': 'Math', 'score': 3},
...  {'full_name': 'Billy Backey', 'subject': 'Math', 'score': 45},
...  {'full_name': 'Donna Love', 'subject': 'Math', 'score': 3},
...  {'full_name': 'Billy Backey', 'subject': 'Math', 'score': 45},
...  {'full_name': 'Douglas Seats', 'subject': 'English', 'score': 51}]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> all_scores = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
>>> for s in a:
...     all_scores[s['full_name']][s['subject']].append(s['score'])
...
```

We now have a dict whose structure is `{full_name: {subject: [score...]}`, and we can iterate over it like this:

```
>>> for full_name, subjects in all_scores.items():
...     for subject, scores in subjects.items():
...         print(f"{full_name} {subject}: {scores}")
...
Douglas Seats English: [51, 51]
Lucille Missey Biology: [19]
Donna Love Math: [3, 3]
Billy Backey Math: [45, 45]
```

The sample data we had for `a` doesn't have any cases where one student has scores in multiple subjects, but the above code would handle those cases if they existed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't want to keep identical scores for the same subjects and the output is a list of dictionaries. This code will achieve that using `groupby` from the `itertools` module.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

name = itemgetter("full_name")
grouped = sorted(a, key=name)

out = []
for k, g in groupby(grouped, key=name):
    tmp = dict()
    for group in g:
        subjects = defaultdict(list)
        subject = group["subject"]
        score = group["score"]
        if score in subjects[subject]:
            continue
        else:
            subjects[subject].append(score)
    tmp[k] = subjects
    out.append(tmp)

print(out)
[{'Billy Backey': defaultdict(list, {'Math': [45]})},
 {'Donna Love': defaultdict(list, {'Math': [3]})},
 {'Douglas Seats': defaultdict(list, {'English': [51]})},
 {'Lucille Missey': defaultdict(list, {'Biology': [19]})}]
```